# What is meant by mobility of entities?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

The book [Pro JPA 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430249269) has to say this about *mobile entities*:

> Client/server and web applications and other distributed architectures
>   are clearly the most popular types of applications in a connected
>   world. To acknowledge this fact meant acknowledging that persistent
>   entities must be mobile in the network. Objects must be able to be
>   moved from one virtual machine to another and then back again, and
>   must still be usable by the application.
>
> Objects that leave the persistence layer are called detached. A key
>   feature of the persistence model is the ability to change detached
>   entities and then reattach them upon their return to the virtual
>   machine. The detachment model provides a way of reconciling the state
>   of an entity being reattached, with the state that it was in before it
>   became detached. This allows entity changes to be made offline, while
>   still maintaining entity consistency in the face of concurrency.

Can someone help me decode the information in the above two paragraphs? Why would some one need the entity to move between JVM's?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that there may be multiple JVMs (multiple mobile devices, multiple servers with a JVM, or any combination thereof).

If I understand it correctly, consider the example of a save-game file. Someone has an account with a website and has a save file stored on the site. But the person downloads the game so they can play it offline.

The save file at this point becomes a 'detached entity'. It is updated 'offline', and is reattached when the user logs in to the website. Updating the entity that is stored server side may be automatic, or the user may be prompted (do you want to overwrite save data? Presents the user with the two save files and timestamps).

Other examples may include

- health data from mobile devices (updated even when out of range of wireless)
- game data
- evernote/similar syncing services
- backup/restore services

Answer (score 0):

The two paragraphs in question are describing the nature of detached objects in `JPA` and correlating them to the concept of `serializability`.

Once an object gets into detached state (i.e is no longer associated with an `entity manager`), it needs a way to reattach itself to a live session. If the object wants to attach itself to an entity manager this is usually done using the `.merge()` operation.

What they mean when they say

> Objects must be able to be moved from one virtual machine to another
>   and then back again, and must still be usable by the application.

is that if you require your object to be sent over through a `remote interface` like over `HTTP` to another application or to a different tier, the object needs a way to move between the applications and to be able to retain its state.

The way to accomplish this is to serialize the object and then send it over the wire - and when it is received on the other end it is reconstructed using the object definition. Then the object needs to attache itself to an entity manager so that it can be persisted. This is what they mean about portability of a detached object.